# How to extract common and remaining parts of two strings in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, cell A1 and B1 contain strings of text. Please teach me how to output the common part of the two strings in cell C1 and the remaining part of the string in A1 after removing the common part in cell D1.

For example, if A1 contains "aabbcc_1" and B1 contains "aabbcc_A", the expected values are:
C1: "aabbcc_"
D1: "1"

What formulas should be entered in cells C1 and D1 to achieve this result?

With the help of Chat GPT, I have created the following Excel formula.
However, when I expand this formula across multiple rows, it does not work as expected. What could be wrong?

[C1 Cell]
`=LEFT(A1,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),1)),0)-1)` 
[D1 Cell]

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(C1))`

I apologize for asking a question that relies on the help of others. If you have any advice, I will do my best to follow it.

Comment: You have multiple rows of data, but have provided only a single solitary example: what happens if the 2 strings are not of the same size, do the contents of column D contain the difference from column A, or from column B ? Do all of your strings contain only Latin characters ? Kindly edit your question to include more examples, sufficient to illustrate the diversity of your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

In Office 365 in `C1` you could use:

```
=REDUCE( "",  SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),
 LAMBDA( x,   y,
         LET( z, MID(A1,y,1),
TEXTJOIN( , 1, x,                         
               IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(z,B1)),z,"")))))
```

The formula checks if it finds the (exact) character in `A1` in the string of `B1`. If it does it joins that character with previous found characters, if any. It will check character by character and during calculation the result of found characters will expand due to `TEXTJOIN`.

In `D1` you could use:

```
=REDUCE( "",  SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),
 LAMBDA( x,   y,
         LET( z, MID(A1,y,1),
TEXTJOIN( , 1, x,                         
               IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(z,B1)),"",z)))))
```

This does the same as the previous formula, but this will add the characters *not* found, rather than found. Further it follows the same logic.

[image]

Or simpler:
`=LET(m,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),CONCAT(REPT(m,ISNUMBER(FIND(m,B1)))))`
and
`=LET(m,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),CONCAT(REPT(m,ISERR(FIND(m,B1)))))`

or in older Excel:
`=CONCAT(REPT(MID(A1,ROW(1:99),1),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,ROW(1:99),1),B1))))`
and
`=CONCAT(REPT(MID(A1,ROW(1:99),1),ISERR(FIND(MID(A1,ROW(1:99),1),B1))))`

These require being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Since somebody upvoted, I looked at the answer again and thought I could add some improvements and options for older Excel versions.

Comment: Also looking for a simple solution to this. This solution works for strings of the same length, but @spectral-instance asked the OP about strings of different length. The solution you provided doesn't take that into account. Can you re-work it so that it does?

Comment: @dholt In that case, I need some samples to show what you expect.